# How to add user input integers to array?

Tags: python

- Declare an empty array
- Let the user add integers to this array, over and over
- Stop when the user enters -1
- Do not add -1 to the array
- Print the array

So far my code below:

```
A=[]
while True:
    B = int(input("Input a continuous amount of integers"))
    A = [B]
    print(A)
    if B == -1:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: `A.append(B)` instead of `A = [B]`?

Comment: `A = [B]` - This won't work. Here you are creating an array of one element, but your task says that you need to "add integers to array". You need to use `append()` method.

Comment: Also this message makes no sense: `input("Input a continuous amount of integers")`. It should probably say: `Input an integer: ` or something.

Comment: For the future please remember what @BurningAlcohol said in his answer: There is a difference between an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) and a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) (here you have a `list`, not an `array`)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, we call the this `[]` datatype as `list`. To *append* item into a list, you can do `A.append(B)`

```
A = []
while True:
    B = int(input("Input a continuous amount of integers"))
    if B == -1:
        break
    else:
        A.append(B) # modify this line
        print(A)
```

Comment: "Do not add -1 to the array"

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if user input is `-1` before appending it to the array and print it in the `if` block, append it in the `else` block.

```
A=[]
while True:
    B = int(input("Input a continuous amount of integers"))
    
    if B == -1:
        print(A)
        break
    else:
        A.append(B)
```